# Dropout for CuDNNLSTM in Keras

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, dropout

We know that `CuDNNLSTM` doesn't support `dropout`. Also, we know `LSTM` layer has two types of dropout in KERAS:

- **dropout**: Fraction of the units to drop for the linear transformation of the inputs.
- **recurrent_dropout**: Float between 0 and 1. Fraction of the units to drop for the linear transformation of the recurrent state.

If I want to use the first type of dropout in `CuDNNLSTM`, can I add a dropout layer before `CuDNNLSTM` in keras? If not, what is the difference of this procedure with `dropout` option in `LSTM`?